# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, opencart

Got a situation with image import process, before asking here of course - tried many ways to solve it by myself, but without any luck yet.
I'm getting error in model file: `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file /.../file.php on line 3875`. Have to mention that - when there's single image - importing that perfectly, as soon as getting multiple images (more than one) - getting this error, and doesn't importing any image, just skipping.

Line 387:  `$image = trim($image);`

Whole function code:

```
    protected function imageHandler($field, &$config, $multiple = false, $item_id = NULL) {
    $image_array = array();
    
    if (empty($config['columns'][$field])) {
      if ($multiple) {
        return $image_array;
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    }
    
    $sort_order = 0;
    
    foreach ((array) $config['columns'][$field] as $images) {
      
      if (!empty($config['multiple_separator']) && is_string($images)) {
        $images = explode(@html_entity_decode($config['multiple_separator']), $images);
      }
      
      //is_array($images) && reset($images);
      
      if ($multiple && is_array($images) && $config['columns']['image'] == $images[key($images)]) {
        array_shift($images);
      }
        
      foreach ((array) $images as $image) {
        $image = trim($image);
        
        if ($config['image_download'] && $image) {
          // if (substr($image, 0, 2) == '//') {
            // $image = 'http:' . $image;
          // }
          
          $file_info = pathinfo(parse_url(trim($image), PHP_URL_PATH));
          
          // if no extension, get it by mime
          if (empty($file_info['extension'])) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($image));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_exec($ch);
            $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
            
            switch($contentType) {
              case 'image/bmp': $file_info['extension'] = 'bmp'; break;
              case 'image/gif': $file_info['extension'] = 'gif'; break;
              case 'image/jpeg': $file_info['extension'] = 'jpg'; break;
              case 'image/pipeg': $file_info['extension'] = 'jfif'; break;
              case 'image/tiff': $file_info['extension'] = 'tif'; break;
              case 'image/png': $file_info['extension'] = 'png'; break;
              default: $file_info['extension'] = '';
            }
          }

          if (substr_count($file_info['dirname'], 'http')) {
            // incorrect array extract
           if (!$multiple) {
              return $image;
            } else {
              $image_array[] = $image;
              continue;
            }
          }
          
          if (!in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'))) {
            $this->session->data['obui_log'][] = array(
              'row' => $this->session->data['obui_current_line'],
              'status' => 'error',
              'title' => $this->language->get('warning'),
              'msg' => $this->language->get('warning_incorrect_image_format') . ' ' . str_replace(' ', '%20', $image),
            );
            
            if (!$multiple) {
              return $image;
            } else {
              $image_array[] = $image;
              continue;
            }
          }
          
          if ($this->simulation) {
            if (!$multiple) {
              /* Now handled before
              if (!in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'))) {
                return array('error_format', $image);
              }*/
              return $image;
            } else {
              /* Now handled before
              if (!in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'))) {
                $image_array[] = 'error_format';
                continue;
              }*/
              $image_array[] = $image;
              continue;
            }
          }
          
          // detect if image is on actual server
          if (strpos($image, 'http') === false) {
            $filename = trim($image);
          
            if (!$multiple) {
              return $filename;
            } else {
              if (!empty($filename)) {
                $image_array[] = array(
                  'image' => $filename,
                  'sort_order' => $sort_order++,
                );
              }
              continue;
            }
          }
          
          if (version_compare(VERSION, '2', '>=')) {
            $path = 'catalog/';
            //$http_path = HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/catalog/';
          } else {
            $path = 'data/';
            //$http_path = HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/data/';
          }
          
          if (trim($config['image_location'], '/\\')) {
            $path .= trim($config['image_location'], '/\\') . '/';
          }
          
          if ($config['image_keep_path'] && trim($file_info['dirname'], '/\\')) {
            $path .= trim($file_info['dirname'], '/\\') . '/';
          }
          
          if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
            mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777, true);
          }
          
          $filename = $path . urldecode($file_info['filename']) . '.' . $file_info['extension'];
          
          if (($item_id === false && $this->config->get('mlseo_insertautoimgname')) || ($item_id && $this->config->get('mlseo_editautoimgname'))) {
            $this->load->model('tool/seo_package');
            $seo_image_name = $this->model_tool_seo_package->transformProduct($this->config->get('mlseo_product_image_name_pattern'), $this->config->get('config_language_id'), $config['columns']);
            
            $seoPath = pathinfo($filename);
            
            if (!empty($seoPath['filename'])) {
              $seoFilename = $this->model_tool_seo_package->filter_seo($seo_image_name, 'image', '', '');
              $filename = $seoPath['dirname'] . '/' . $seoFilename . '.' . $seoPath['extension'];
              
              if (file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
                $x = 1;
                
                while (file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
                  $filename = $seoPath['dirname'] . '/' . $seoFilename . '-' . $x . '.' . $seoPath['extension'];
                  $x++;
                }
              }
            }
          } 
          
          if ($config['image_exists'] == 'rename') {
            $x = 1;
            while (file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
              $filename = $path . urldecode($file_info['filename']) . '-' . $x++ . '.' . $file_info['extension'];
            }
          } else if ($config['image_exists'] == 'keep' && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            // image skipped
            if (!$multiple) {
              return $filename;
            } else {
              $image_array[] = array(
                'image' => $filename,
                'sort_order' => $sort_order++,
              );
              
              continue;
            }
          }
        
          // copy image, replace space chars for compatibility with copy()
          // if (!@copy(trim(str_replace(' ', '%20', $image)), DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
          $copyError = $this->copy_image(trim(str_replace(' ', '%20', $image)), DIR_IMAGE . $filename);
          
          if ($copyError !== true) {
            if (defined('GKD_CRON')) {
              $this->cron_log($this->session->data['obui_current_line'] . ' - ' . $copyError);
            } else {
              $this->session->data['obui_log'][] = array(
                'row' => $this->session->data['obui_current_line'],
                'status' => 'error',
                'title' => $this->language->get('warning'),
                'msg' => $copyError,
              );
            }
            
            $filename = '';
          }
          
        } else {
          // get direct value
          $filename = trim($image);
          
          if ($this->simulation) {
            if (!$multiple) {
              return $filename;
            } else {
              if (!empty($filename)) {
                $image_array[] = $filename;
              }
              continue;
            }
          }
        }
        
        // one field only, directly return first value
        if (!$multiple) {
          return $filename;
        }
        
        if (!empty($filename)) {
          $image_array[] = array(
            'image' => $filename,
            'sort_order' => $sort_order++,
          );
        }
      }
    }
    
    return $image_array;
  }
```

Tried to use return $image; after that line, even that didn't helped. Was trying to find similar problem to this one to find a solution without posting here, but seems like I won't move anywhere withou help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try ```var_dump($image)``` just before the line that gives an error. you'll see the actual state of a variable for that moment and then can figure out from where the problem comes.

Comment: then ```var_dump($image);ob_flush();exit();``` just before that line, this should force the output of vardump to browser

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know what the variables are. As the question is now, we can't help you.

Comment: Getting result: `string(77) "https://.../files/images/fd9aff.jpg"` which is really strange, does that mean it doesn't recognizing there's multiple images?

Comment: `$image` in here is definitely a string. Because it's going after `foreach ((array) $images as $image) {` . You can `var_dump($images);` before `foreach`. Can you tell if it's some core Opencart file? Where can i see working example in Opencart ?

Comment: better `var_dump($config['columns'][$field]);` right after `$sort_order = 0;`

Comment: After sort order var_dump shows me: `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["photo"]=> string(77) "https://.../export/cdfd9aff.jpg" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["photo"]=> string(77) "https://.../export/c14aee0.jpg" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["photo"]=> string(77) "https://.../export/c44d4d3e.jpg" } }` it looks like foreach getting all existing results, but can't store it properly, and have no clue why